# How to make editable datagridviewComboBox

Tags: vb.net, combobox

How can I make an editable datagridviewComboBox?  What I mean by editable, is that the user can type a value, not just select from a drop-down list.

This C# solution, that I adapt to VB.Net, almost works for me (https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-create-editable-combobox-cell-in-datagridview1):

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlsShowingEventArgs e) {
  if (dataGridView1.CurrentCellAddress.X == column1.DisplayIndex) {
    ComboBox cb = e.Control as ComboBox;
    if (cb != null) {
      cb.DropDownStyle = DropDown;
    }
  }
}
```

However, when I type an entry into the combobox and click return, the entry is not saved and the combobox goes empty to `""`.

Can somebody help?  Thanks.